# RMI naming lookup throws UnmarshalException caused by ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, rmi

in below RMI service verification on remote method is not working when used naming.lookup(). it does not give any error but does not return remote interface value. But was able to find when searched for all services running on that serve

```
Registry reg;
String serverAddress = "xxxxx";
String serverPort = "xxxx";
String text = "x";
try {
    reg= LocateRegistry.getRegistry(serverAddress, (new Integer(serverPort)).intValue());
    final String regsitryList[] = registry.list();
    // Remote r = registry.lookup("xservice") ;
    if (Arrays.asList(regsitryList).contains("xservice")) {
        Remote r = registry.lookup("xservice");
        if(r!=null)
        log.debug("found the service");
    }
} catch (RemoteException re) {
    re.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: So what *does* it return? Can you *cast* that to the remote interface?

Comment: no I don't what does it return, because requirement is that just check if service is up and running and don't need capture return.

Comment: So if you don't know what it returns, how can you possibly know it isn't an instance of the remote interface? What on earth is your question? And why are you calling both list() and lookup()?

Comment: I am not calling both. they are just for testing. my question is if it is found using list, why is not found using lookup()

Comment: Just a minute. If it isn't found using `lookup()` it will throw a `NotBoundException,` but you said above that it 'does not give any error'. `lookup()` therefore returned something. What? Note that I asked you the same question two days ago and you still haven't answered it.

Comment: it returned marshaling error at the line lookup();

Comment: No, it didn't return anything. It *threw* an `UnmarshalException.` In other words it ***did*** give an error! Please edit the stack trace into your post. Why does it take two days to get the most basic information?

Comment: EJP, I am way from work for last two days! so did not remember what was the error

Comment: so I understand from your post, if we don't handle the return from lookup(), it will give error. so best way to just check if remote service is running in my case is that that just use list() right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception that you claimed didn't happen will almost certainly be due to a `ClassNotFoundException` mentioning the remote interface or the stub, or a class that they depend on. When you call `list()` you're only retreiving Strings, not the class of the object, so there is no exception.

`list()` and `lookup()` both tell you whether the object is currently bound in the Registry. That doesn't by itself mean that the object still exists. You would have to execute a remote method on it to know that; and for that you would need the missing class(es).

Comment: Thank you. You can see it would have been a lot quicker if you had described your problem properly and included the stack trace, instead of just saying things like 'not able', and 'does not give an error' when it did.